# Why does the acquire() method in Semaphores not have to be synchronized?

Tags: java, synchronization, semaphore

I am getting into Semaphores in Java and was reading this article http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html . The only thing I don't get is why the acquire() method is not used in a synchronized context. Looking at the example from the above webiste:

They create a semaphore:

```
private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(100);
```

and get a permit just like this:

```
semaphore.acquire();
```

Now, wouldn't it be possible that two or more threads try to acquire() at the same time? If so, there would be a little problem with the count.

Or, does the semaphore itself handle the synchronization?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Or, does the semaphore itself handle the synchronization?

Yes that's basically it. Semaphores are thread safe as explained in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html):

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to calling a "release" method such as release() happen-before actions following a successful "acquire" method such as acquire() in another thread.

Most operations on the objects in the `java.util.concurrent` package are thread safe. More details are provided at the very bottom of the [package javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 3):

Semaphores ought to be fast and therefore use the atomic concurrency primitives from the `Unsafe` class, like [CAS (compare and swap)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap).

With these primitives synchronization happens on a much lower level and monitors are not needed. (Lock-free synchronization).

In fact the synchronization is performed by a loop continously using CAS until the expected value equals the written/read value.

Answer (score 0):

synchronization is guaranteed by AbstractQueuedSynchronizer with CAS operations

see the [javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html) here